# Asynchronous Behavior and Performance Issues with FFmpeg Processing, Firebase Function and Firebase Storage Uploads

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I've implemented a function that activates upon uploading a video file to Firebase Storage. This function utilizes Fluent FFmpeg to split the video into segments and then saves these clips back into storage. During testing, I uploaded a 500MB video, approximately 3 minutes long, and segmented it into 36 clips of 5 seconds each, resulting in 36 files. The process initially seemed efficient: the function itself completed in about 30 seconds. However, I noticed that the FFmpeg processing continued independently, taking an additional 18 minutes. Subsequently, uploading the segments back to storage required a further 59 minutes.

I am running this on a 1st generation Firebase function with 2GB of memory and a 60-second timeout setting. Based on this setup, I have a couple of concerns:

1. Is it typical for the Firebase function to complete successfully while the FFmpeg task continues to run in parallel, asynchronously?
2. What could be causing the significant delay in saving the segmented files back to Firebase Storage, and are there any strategies to improve this performance?

I appreciate insights or suggestions on how to address these issues, especially ways to optimize the storage saving step.

Here is my code

```
exports.segmentVideo = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(
async (object) => {
  const filePath = object.name;

  if (filePath.startsWith("test/")) {
    console.log("1. Segmentation STARTED");
    const fileName = filePath.split("/").pop();
    const bucketName = object.bucket;
    const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
    const tempSegmentFolder = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "mySegments");

    try {
      await fs.mkdir(tempSegmentFolder, {recursive: true});
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error creating temp folder:", err);
      return;
    }

    await storage.bucket(bucketName)
        .file(filePath)
        .download({destination: tempLocalFile});

    const metadata = object.metadata;
    const segmentDuration = metadata.segmentDuration ?
        parseInt(metadata.segmentDuration, 10) :
        30;
    const userEmail = metadata.userEmail;
    console.log("2. Processing video with FFmpeg");

    ffmpeg(tempLocalFile)
        .outputOptions([
          `-f segment`,
          `-segment_time ${segmentDuration}`,
          `-reset_timestamps 1`,
          `-c copy`,
          //              `-c:v libx264`, // Re-encode video with H.264
          //              `-c:a aac`, // Re-encode audio with AAC
        ])
        .output(path.join(tempSegmentFolder,
            `output_${fileName}_%03d.mp4`))
        .on("start", (commandLine) => {
          console.log(`FFmpeg started with command: ${commandLine}`);
        })
        .on("progress", (progress) => {
          console.log(`Processing: ${progress.percent}% done`);
        })
        .on("error", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          console.error(`Error occurred: ${err.message}`);
          console.log(`FFmpeg stdout:\n${stdout}`);
          console.log(`FFmpeg stderr:\n${stderr}`);
        })


        .on("end", async () => {
          console.log("Segmentation finished");

          const files = await fs.readdir(tempSegmentFolder);
          const segmentedFiles = files.filter((file) =>
            file.startsWith(`output_${fileName}`) &&
        file.endsWith(".mp4"));

          const segmentUrls = []; // Array to hold URLs of uploaded segments

          for (const file of segmentedFiles) {
            const destination = `segments/${file}`;
            await storage.bucket(bucketName)
                .upload(path.join(tempSegmentFolder, file), {destination});

            // Using Firebase Admin SDK to get the download URL
            const fileUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucketName}/o/${encodeURIComponent(destination)}?alt=media`;
            segmentUrls.push(fileUrl);
            console.log(`Link ${file}:${fileUrl}`);

            console.log(`Uploaded ${file} to ${destination}`);
          }

          // Sending an email with the video links
          // Ensure userEmail is fetched from metadata
          // and sendEmail function is defined
          if (userEmail && segmentUrls.length > 0) {
            await sendEmail(userEmail, segmentUrls)
                .then(() => console
                    .log("Email sent successfully."))
                .catch((error) => console
                    .error("Failed to send email:", error));
          } else {
            console.log("Email not sent: User email is missing" +
            "\nor no segments to send.");
          }


          await Promise.all(segmentedFiles.map((file) =>
            fs.unlink(path.join(tempSegmentFolder, file))));
          await fs.rm(tempSegmentFolder, {recursive: true, force: true});
        })
        .run();
  } else {
    console.log("File not in target folder");
  }
});
```

Comment: it will be better if you add the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ,to look at

Comment: full code just added

Answer (score 0):

try the belown, i added my highlighted changes with comment starting with `//<--` .

```
exports.segmentVideo = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(
  async (object) => {
    const filePath = object.name;

    if (filePath.startsWith("test/")) {
      console.log("1. Segmentation STARTED");
      const fileName = filePath.split("/").pop();
      const bucketName = object.bucket;
      const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
      const tempSegmentFolder = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "mySegments");

      try {
        await fs.mkdir(tempSegmentFolder, { recursive: true });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error creating temp folder:", err);
        return;
      }

      await storage.bucket(bucketName)
        .file(filePath)
        .download({ destination: tempLocalFile });

      const metadata = object.metadata;
      const segmentDuration = metadata.segmentDuration
        ? parseInt(metadata.segmentDuration, 10)
        : 30;
      const userEmail = metadata.userEmail;
      console.log("2. Processing video with FFmpeg");

      const ffmpegPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg(tempLocalFile)
          .outputOptions([
            `-f segment`,
            `-segment_time ${segmentDuration}`,
            `-reset_timestamps 1`,
            `-c copy`,
          ])
          .output(path.join(tempSegmentFolder, `output_${fileName}_%03d.mp4`))
          .on("start", (commandLine) => {
            console.log(`FFmpeg started with command: ${commandLine}`);
          })
          .on("progress", (progress) => {
            console.log(`Processing: ${progress.percent}% done`);
          })
          .on("error", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.error(`Error occurred: ${err.message}`);
            console.log(`FFmpeg stdout:\n${stdout}`);
            console.log(`FFmpeg stderr:\n${stderr}`);
            reject(err);
          })
          .on("end", () => {
            console.log("Segmentation finished");
            resolve();
          })
          .run();
      });

      const uploadPromises = [];

      ffmpegPromise.then(async () => {
        const files = await fs.readdir(tempSegmentFolder);
        const segmentedFiles = files.filter(
          (file) =>
            file.startsWith(`output_${fileName}`) && file.endsWith(".mp4")
        );

        const segmentUrls = []; // Array to hold URLs of uploaded segments

        for (const file of segmentedFiles) {
          const destination = `segments/${file}`;
          const uploadPromise = storage
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .upload(path.join(tempSegmentFolder, file), { destination })
            .then(() => {                 //<-- use then to ensure the upload occer and then move to next
              // Using Firebase Admin SDK to get the download URL
              const fileUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucketName}/o/${encodeURIComponent(
                destination
              )}?alt=media`;
              segmentUrls.push(fileUrl);
              console.log(`Link ${file}:${fileUrl}`);
              console.log(`Uploaded ${file} to ${destination}`);
            })
            .catch((error) => {  //<-- catch if any 
              console.error(`error occered ... at catch while uploading then file: ${fileName}:`, error);
            });

          uploadPromises.push(uploadPromise);
        }

      
        await Promise.all(uploadPromises);// <--await to complet uploadPromises 

        // Sending an email with the video links
        // Ensure userEmail is fetched from metadata
        // and sendEmail function is defined
        if (userEmail && segmentUrls.length > 0) {
          await sendEmail(userEmail, segmentUrls)
            .then(() => console.log("Email sent successfully."))
            .catch((error) => console.error("Failed to send email:", error));
        } else {
          console.log(
            "Email not sent: User email is missing or no segments to send."
          );
        }


        await Promise.all(
          segmentedFiles.map((file) =>
            fs.unlink(path.join(tempSegmentFolder, file))
          )
        );
        await fs.rm(tempSegmentFolder, { recursive: true, force: true });
      });

      return ffmpegPromise;
    } else {
      console.log("File not in target folder");
    }
  }
);
```